# How to iterate over multiple keys using JSON_VALUE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have JSON stored in the database, that looks like this:

```
{
    "EmpName": "John Doe",
    "Department": "IT",
    "Address-1": "101, Sector 1, NY",
    "Address-2": "102, Sector 2, SC",
    "Address-3": "103, Sector 3, NY",
    "Address-4": "104, Sector 4, NY",
    "Salary": 100000
}
```

I am trying to check if the json has the address "102, Sector 2, SC" in it or not using `JSON_VALUE`.

But there can be multiple addresses for a single JSON object, which are indexed like Address-1/2/3/4

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
select * 
from emp
where JSON_VALUE(emp.index_data, '$."Address-[*]"') = '102, Sector 2, SC'
```

I know we cannot have that '[*]' in the key, but is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: look up the documentation for `openjson`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An option if you don't know the exact column names, is to use `OPENJSON` without a schema:**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM OPENJSON(emp.index_data) j
    WHERE j.[key] LIKE 'Address-%' AND
        j.[value] = '102, Sector 2, SC'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(emp.index_data)
with(
        varAddressLine1 nvarchar(Max) '$.Address-1',
        varAddressLine2 nvarchar(Max) '$.Address-2',
        varAddressLine3 nvarchar(Max) '$.Address-3',
        varAddressLine4 nvarchar(Max) '$.Address-4'
    )
where varAddressLine1 = '102, Sector 2, SC'
OR varAddressLine2 = '102, Sector 2, SC'
OR varAddressLine3 = '102, Sector 2, SC'
OR varAddressLine4 = '102, Sector 2, SC'
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? It's normaly considered good form to explain your suggestions/answers. Code only answers can be surprisingly uninformative, even if they are technically correct. A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: The number of addresses can vary, that is the tricky part here.
But your solution is good for someone looking over fixed number of keys.

Comment: For your version `where '102, Sector 2, SC' IN (varAddressLine1, varAddressLine2, varAddressLine3, varAddressLine4)` is a bit shorter